# missing 'typename' prior to dependent type name

Tags: c++, templates, typedef

I got the following struct:

```
template<typename GRAPHEDGE>
struct DOTFormatWrapper
{

    typedef GRAPHEDGE::Node Node;
    // code

};
```

Graphedge of course has an internal type "Node"

Compiling produces the error "encode.hpp:19:10: error: missing 'typename' prior to dependent type name 'GRAPHEDGE::Node'"

I don't understand... I have the template type declared before the typdef. Could somebody explain to me what the mistake is?

Comment: `typename` is in quotation marks, meaning the compiler is literally telling you exactly what to put and exactly where to put it.

Comment: I see, thanks. Though I only vaguely understand the explanation in the other thread.